# Возможно, в предложении что-то не согласовано?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Выходя, столкнулся с группой туристов, в колонну по одному движущейся в затылок направляющему (он же гид).*

Comment: Столкнуться одному — с группой по одному идущей? Столкнуться с группой может только соразмерное ей. Натолкнуться на... Уткнуться в...

Comment: Исправил, но "несогласованность" осталась.

Answer (score 2):

С согласованием все в порядке. Фраза тяжеловесная, но может, так и задумано?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь рассогласованы по времени глагол и причастие; плохо воспринимается "группа, движущаяся в колонну" (лучше переключить на "туристов", которые ближе по тексту). При описании способа движения два его аспекта (как однородные элементы формального описания) нужно перечислить через запятую (иначе "в затылок" воспринимается как *буквальное* направление движения):

> При выходе он столкнулся с группой туристов, *двигавшихся* *колонной* по
>   одному, в затылок направляющему.

**P.S.** Из "Корпусной грамматики". http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#32

> *3.2. Обязательный выбор действительных причастий прошедшего или настоящего времени
>   
> 3.2.2. Действительные причастия глаголов НСВ
>   
> 3.2.2.3. Действительные причастия глаголов НСВ при опорной форме в прошедшем времени 
> 5) относительное предшествование и абсолютное
>   прошедшее* [наш случай: действие причастия предшествовало
>   "столкновению"].

Comment: *Здесь рассогласованы по времени глагол и причастие* – и ничего страшного. Где-то есть правило об обязательном согласовании?

Comment: Есть правило здравого смысла: в данном примере из прошедшего времени глагола и настоящего времени причастия следует, что колонна, с которой столкновение уже произошло, продолжает идти и в момент рассказа. Такое возможно только при репортаже в реальном времени - едва ли в вопросе такой случай. Даже если при повествовании использован приём переноса в настоящее время, то _оба_ элемента должны быть в настоящем (напр. "и тут он сталкивается с идущей колонной группой").

Comment: Нет в языке такого прямолинейного "здравого смысла". Подобных фраз полно.

Comment: @Alex_ander === Из "Корпусной грамматики": Сложнее всего обстоит дело в ситуации типа 4), то есть тогда, когда при помощи действительного причастия глагола НСВ необходимо обозначить действие, одновременное действию, выраженному опорной формой прошедшего времени. В таких случаях грамматически возможны (и часто семантически более или менее эквивалентны друг другу) оказываются причастия настоящего времени, с одной стороны, и причастия прошедшего времени, с другой, как в следующем сконструированном примере:

(22) _Я хорошо видел человека, **выходящего / выходившего** из дома напротив_.

Comment: Я рассматривал наш пример на предмет принадлежности варианту 4. В источнике нет примеров, относящих однократное пересечение действий к одновременности и связанной с этим _двоякой_ ("конкурентной" в их терминологии)  возможности. "Видел" в их примере - продолжающее действие (видел, как он выходит) и потому трактуется как одновременное. У нас же - однократное и завершённое (у них лишь регулярно повторяющиеся трактуются как "одновременные"); не важно, продолжала ли после столкновения группа двигаться - ситуация завершается столкновением, при котором движение группы явно начиналось раньше (вар.5).

Comment: Выходя, натолкнулся на группу туристов, двигавшихся колонной по одному в затылок направляющему (он же гид).  Исправил, несогласованность исчезла. (Надо же, какую полемику вызвал простой вопрос...))

Comment: @Виктор А как же — «... нужно перечислить через запятую (иначе "в затылок" воспринимается как буквальное направление движения)»?

Comment: Ок. Добавил запятую.